Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getBalance')
hello guys im running into an error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getBalance')
const { ethers, deployments, getNamedAccounts } = require("hardhat")
const { expect, assert } = require("chai")
const sendValue = "1000000000000000000"

describe("FundMe", function () {
    let fundMe
    let deployer
    let mockV3Aggregator

    beforeEach(async function () {
        // Get the deployer account from named accounts
        const accounts = await getNamedAccounts()
        deployer = accounts.deployer

        // Deploy the contracts using the deployer account
        await deployments.fixture(["all"])
        fundMe = await ethers.getContract("FundMe", deployer)
        mockV3Aggregator = await ethers.getContract(
            "MockV3Aggregator",
            deployer
        )
    })

    describe("constructor", function () {
        it("sets the aggregator address correctly", async function () {
            const response = await fundMe.getPriceFeed()
            assert.equal(response, mockV3Aggregator.target)
        })
    })

    describe("fund", function () {
        it("fails if you don't send enough ETH", async function () {
            await expect(fundMe.fund()).to.be.revertedWith(
                "You need to spend more ETH!"
            )
        })

        it("updates the amount funded data structure", async function () {
            const sendValue = ethers.parseEther("1") // 1 ETH
            await fundMe.fund({ value: sendValue, from: deployer })

            const response = await fundMe.addressToAmountFunded(deployer)
            assert.equal(response.toString(), sendValue.toString())
        })
        it("adds funders to array of funders", async function () {
            await fundMe.fund({ value: sendValue })
            const funder = await fundMe.funders(0)
            assert.equal(funder, deployer)
        })
    })
    describe("withdraw", async function () {
        beforeEach(async function () {
            await fundMe.fund({ value: sendValue })
        })

        it("Withdraw ETH from a single founder", async function () {
            //arrange
            const startingFundMeBalance = await fundMe.provider.getBalance(
                fundMe.target
            )
            const startingDeployerBalance = await fundMe.provider.getBalance(
                deployer.target
            )
            //act
            const transactionResponse = await fundMe.withdraw()
            const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait(1)

            const endingFundMeBalance = await fundMe.provider.getBalance(
                fundMe.target
            )
            const endingDeployerBalance = await fundMe.provider.getBalance(
                deployer.target
            )
            //asser.
            assert.equal(endingFundMeBalance, 0)
            assert.equal(
                startingFundMeBalance.add(startingDeployerBalance).toString(),
                endingDeployerBalance.toString()
            )
        })
    })
})


The.getAddress() returns the same error, could anyone tell the error?

Try ethers.provider.getBalance(deployer.target)

You are facing this problem due to the change in the etherjs verson , just change the line having your fundMe.provider.getBalance(fundMe.target) to
ethers.provider.getBalance(fundMe.target)
That is from :
const startingFundMeBalance = await fundMe.provider.getBalance(fundMe.target)
to:
const startingFundMeBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(fundMe.target)
Also deployer is an address , so deployer.target will throw an error , so change that line from
const startingDeployerBalance = await fundMe.provider.getBalance(deployer.target)
to
const startingDeployerBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(deployer)
Do the same with Ending Balances too.

thank you so much harigovind mg

@vatsalsharma , if the answer helped you , can you mark it as the answer :)
